# How to test a script which loads a google maps with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, jasmine

I'm having difficulties in writing tests for a page which loads a google maps. I'm always getting the error

> " Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined "

which means that when the map script loads the div that i use to hold the map probably has already been removed (i'm setting width and height in the style property of the div to be 100% sure that it has a width and height).

I'm loading my gmaps script in a pretty complex way that involves requirejs but i don't think that the issue is related to that (even if i get an error from requirejs when i run the specRunner, but everything works fine live).

How should i test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `waitFor()` and it worked.

```
describe( "Test suite for the 'Event location' Box", function() {
    it( "Should show the map when the appropriate checkbok is clicked and should hide it when clicked again", function() {
        // Wait for the loading of the gmaps. This is simply when the <div> we use as a container has some html
        waitsFor(function() {
            return $('#ai1ec_map_canvas').html() !== '';
        }, "gmaps never loaded", 15000 );
        runs( function() {
            $( "#ai1ec_google_map" ).click();
            expect( $( '#ai1ec_map_canvas' ) ).toBeVisible();
            $( "#ai1ec_google_map" ).click();
            expect( $( '#ai1ec_map_canvas' ) ).not.toBeVisible();
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Any chance you can post your full solution? I'm running into the same issue with a unit test for a directive, and have tried the waitsFor solution, but I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null` when (for example) `$compile('<map></map>')(scope);` is called in a Jasmine 'it' block. Asking here before creating a new SO post with an example.

Comment: @StephenSpann the one above is the solution, i wait until some html appears in the empty canvas i use to hold the google map. When it's not empty anymore i run the tests. basically waitsFor goes on until the function you provided doesn't return true.